# How do I allow a Silverlight popup to size to its content but prevent it from growing?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I am creating a Silverlight dialog class which is more MVVM-friendly. The `ChildWindow` class has some awkwardness which makes it difficult to manage from a view model.

This means I need to declare my own user interface. I have all of the traditional elements in place, including a `Popup` control and an overlay with 50% opacity. The open/close behavior is also working.

The problem I am having is that my control template doesn't prevent the dialog body from growing in response to the user typing into a `TextBox`. When the amount of characters grows beyond the default size, the entire dialog body stretches horizontally. Obviously this is not normal behavior.

What I would like to accomplish is a way for the dialog body to size itself appropriately to the content, but not expand or contract in response to child controls which require more or less space. This is how the `ChildWindow` control behaves, but I have examined [its template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833070%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and I can't determine how that works.

I think I am seeing the expansion behavior because my template is based on `Grid`s, which allow child controls as much size as they request. I have tried several permutations of `StackPanel`, `ScrollViewer`, and other layouts with no success. Does anyone have some insight into how `ChildWindow` accomplishes its static, content-sized layout, or perhaps another suggestion?

Here is the template I have so far, stripped down to the bare essentials:

```
<Popup>
    <Grid x:Name="overlay">
        <Border>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                    ...Title...
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding DialogBody}" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Popup>
```

When `DialogBody` contains a `TextBox` or anything else which changes the layout size, such as hidden controls, the entire content of the `Popup` grows. I don't want to resort to a static width and height, because I want the dialog to automatically size to the dialog body, *but only initially*.

Comment: This is interesting.  I'm using a floatable child window that is fired from a behavior.  I have a few more to implement that have user entry, I wonder if I'll have the same problem.  I'll post my results since the floatable child window inherits child window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that this is wat you want..., but
wyh don't you register for Loaded event of "overlay" nad when Load will fire set the heigh and width  of "overlay" ActualHeight and ActualWidth accordingly.
In this way control will get the size it want initially and wont change after that.

EDIT:
you can use this to do this in declarative way.

```
  <Grid.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard x:Name ="setWidth">
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="overlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="0" To="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=overlay}"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="overlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="0" To="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=overlay}"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Grid.Triggers>
```

Comment: I was hoping to implement this solely in a declarative fashion, but I put your suggestion in place and it works exactly as I needed. I altered the approach slightly, setting the `Width` and `Height` of the `ContentControl` to the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of the `DialogBody` control. I gave this answer a +1 and will accept it if no one answers with a declarative approach in the next few days. Thanks.

Comment: Edited my original post.
seems this should help.
now it will animate , but you can set duration to 0 if you want.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. I assumed you couldn't use triggers in Silverlight; I didn't realize the single `Loaded` event is supported. I should have been more specific when I said "declarative approach". I meant an approach which uses a combination of layout elements to achieve the bounding I need, sans behavior. Your suggestion is working for me right now; I am just curious if I was not clever enough with my `Grid`s and such and would love some insight. You will probably get the green checkmark, I just want to leave it open to encourage other answers. Thanks.